# Batch file to check os architecture and then execute appropriate exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file which will ease the process of installing drivers for our users.

The batch file needs to check what version of os (64bit or 32bit) the code is running on and then execute the appropriate `.exe`.

This is what I have so far:

```
set os_version=wmic os get osarchitecture
echo "%os_version%"
pause

IF os_version = "64-bit"
@run 64 bit
start /d "%0" CP210xVCPInstaller_x64.exe
ELSE
@run 32 bit
start /d  "%0" CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe
```

Now I am having an issue with assigning the output of the command `wmic os get osarchitecture` to a variable.

Then I need to check if it is equal to `64-bit` and if so execute a `.exe` in the same location as the bat file?

Second Question is how do I run a `.exe` from the same directory as the bat file?

Comment: Why not just use %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%?  It is set to AMD64 regardless of whether it is Intel or AMD.

Comment: Hope you are aware that wmic will ask a question the first time you run it on a virgin machine.  This may cause the script with wmic to fail the very first time and work correctly on subsequent times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simpler:

```
if exist "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\" (
   start "" /d "%~dp0" "CP210xVCPInstaller_x64.exe"
) else (
   start "" /d "%~dp0" "CP210xVCPInstaller_x86.exe"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture^|find /i "bits"') do set "bits=%%a"
echo %bits%
```

This will handle the "How" to assign the output to the variable. To avoid problems, only the first token in the output of wmic is retrieved (from `32 bits` or `64 bits`, only the numbers)

Answer (score 2):

MC ND's method needs to be changed to the following...

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture ^| find /i "bit"') do set "bits=%%a"
echo %bits%
```

Notice the difference in the `find /i "bit"` vs `find /i "bits"`.  Using "bits" will not work as the OSArchitecture only returns 32-bit or 64-bit, not bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist %windir%/syswow64 (
   start "" /d "%~dp0"/64 bit program (PE d+) path
) else (
   start "" /d "%~dp0"/32 bit program (PE L) path
)
```