# How can I identify if an OS is 64 bit or 32 bit with a windows batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

> TL;DR : I need a piece of code that can identify the "bit" of windows and puts it in a variable called "bit", without any user input.

Currently, I am just using:

```
set /P choice=32 bit system? [Y/N]

    if /I "%choice%" EQU "Y" (
        :: 32 bit code
    ) else (
        :: 64 bit code
    )
```

But, I want something to identify if a user is using a 32/64 bit system no matter if they are running a 32/64 bit command prompt or the bit of there computer. In the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322308/batch-file-to-check-64bit-or-32bit-os) there answer only states how to do it if you run the correct bit version of CMD.

[Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo), a user on the site, helped me in the past with identifying what version of windows a user is running which reduced the number of user inputs a lot; however, I still haven't found a clean solution for the "bit" of windows.

Comment: have you done a search before asking? [Batch to detect if system is a 32-bit or 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990839/995714), [Batch file to check os architecture and then execute appropriate exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22143039/995714), [If Processor=xx-bit do this in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42044600/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "x86" (
    rem 32 bit
) else (
    rem 64 bit
)
```

There's a slight complication if someone's running the 32 bit command prompt on a 64 bit system (where it will identify as 32 bit, even though the OS is 64 bit), but that can be fixed using:

```
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "x86" (
    if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%" EQU "AMD64" (
        rem 64 bit OS, but running a 32 bit command prompt
    ) else (
        rem 32 bit OS
    )
) else (
    rem 64 bit OS
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can chain those two IFs -- `IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%"=="AMD64" (`.